# Postgresql filter results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assumeing I have a table `Foo`

```
id | startDate | startTime | endTime | name
```

I am trying to find occurrences that "pass midnight"...`start < 00:00:00` and `end > 00:00:00`

I can use the following to get the times

```
select extract (epoch from (endTime - startTime)) as time from Foo
```

but how can I add a constraint that allows me to filter the return values for only those < 0 (which should be those satisfying the "midnight" property)

I tried

```
select extract (epoch from (endTime - startTime)) as timeSpent from Foo where timeSpent < 0
ERROR:  column "timeSpent" does not exist
```

Comment: Do you mean an INSERT constraint? Such that only data that passes a certain test is allowed to be inserted into your table?

Comment: @CodyCaughlan I'll edit the question (including bad code) that I think will clarify

Comment: `time` is a reserved word in PG; so pick a different name

Comment: @CodyCaughlan, I've changed the question but the problem will remains.

Comment: What data type are the columns `starttime` and `endtime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference an alias on the same level where you define it. You need to wrap that in a derived table:

```
select * 
from (
  select extract (epoch from (endTime - startTime)) as timeSpent 
  from Foo 
) t 
where timespent < 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would think about doing is creating a sub-query that isolates the part of the date that denotes the day, and writing a statement that roughly equates to:

```
WHERE [start day] != [end day]
```

This will enable you to extract a specific date from the table.

Comment: I would, but the time stamps are 24 hour. The table does however have a "start date"...

Comment: Note that `[start day]` is an invalid identifier in SQL. To use an identifier that contains a space you need to use double quotes: e.g. `"start day"`